# How I change the GitLab accessToken time expiration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth to login with gitlab, but every 2 hours my accessToken changes, how can I keep it for a long period of time and thus register in my database. NOTE: I am creating a service to list all client repositories.

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import GitLabProvider from 'next-auth/providers/gitlab';
import axios from 'axios';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GitLabProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'api' } },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: async (session, user) => {
      if (!session.accessToken) {
        return session;
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({
      token, user, account,
    }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
});
```

Comment: You can check the doc here : https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/refresh-token-rotation

Answer (score 0):

Check if [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#token-rotation-api) (May 2023) can help:

> ### Token rotation API
>
> Previously, to rotate tokens, the token owner had to manually create a new token and replace the existing token.
>
> Now, token owners can use a `:rotate` API endpoint to programatically rotate personal, group, and project access tokens.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/token_overview.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/403042).